How to Modify Middleware to Handle Two Route Groups in Next.js
I'm working on a Next.js project where I have two route groups, (auth) which contains my auth pages and (root) which contains the dashbaord and other pages and a homepage "/. I have a middleware function that redirects requests to the sign-in path found in the (auth) route group "(auth)/sign-in"
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    const cookieStore = cookies()
    const accessToken = cookieStore.get('accessToken');

    if (!accessToken && request.nextUrl.pathname !== '/') {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/sign-in', request.url))
    }
}

export const config = {
    /*
         * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with:
         * - api (API routes)
         * - auth (authentication routes)
         * - _next/static (static files)
         * - _next/image (image optimization files)
         * - *.png (PNG image files)
         */
    matcher: ["/((?!api|auth|_next/static|_next/image|.*\\.png$).*)"],
}

Here is my project structure
src
│
├── app/
│   ├── (auth)/
│   │   ├── sign-in
│   │   |   ├── page.tsx
│   │   ├── layout.tsx
│   │
│   ├── (root)/
│   │   ├── dashboard/
|   |   |   ├── page.tsx
│   |   ├── layout.tsx
|   |
│   ├── page.tsx
│   ├── layout.tsx
│   └── ...
│
├── middleware.tsx
│
└── ...

How can I modify this middleware to handle both the (auth) and (root) route groups effectively?
I tried using regex as above, but it doesn't work for other routes inside the (root) group
Any help or insights would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!
I tried using regex as above but it doesn't work for other routes inside the (root) group

It seems not possible yet, see this issue: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/44635

I just left the implementation the same , it works so i'm not touching it
